# Blazor NavigationManager Return "/?"

Tags: asp.net-core, navigation, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am using Blazor for my web project. I am learning this framework but I have got a problem. If I want to go another page, I can this:

```
<a href="DetailsPage" class="btn btn-primary">Details</a>
```

Now, I create a login page (My index page and URL is https://5000) and I check user information. I can't any authorization. If this informations are true, the user goes to homepage, else the user stays login page. But, when I try true information and click login button, I go to homepage (https://5000/homepage) and return the login page (https://5000/?) again. When I return login page, my URL is "https://5000/?". Why I return my login page and I see "?".

```
@page "/"
@using MyProject.Data
@using System.Net.Http
@inject HttpClient Http
@inject IMatToaster Toaster
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="UserName">User Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name" @bind="@UserName">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="UserPassword">User Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="User Password" @bind="@UserPassword">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@Login">Log In</button>
</form>

@code {

    private User[] UserList;
    private User[] Control;

    public string UserName, UserPassword;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await getData();
    }

    protected async Task getData()
    {
        UserList = await Http.GetJsonAsync<User[]>("/api/Users/");
    }

    protected void Login()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserPassword))
        {
        }
        else
        {
            Control = UserList.Where(A => A.UserName.Equals(UserName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && A.UserPassword == UserPassword).ToArray();
            if (Control.Length == 0)
            {   
            }
            else
            {
                NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/homepage");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that you use `<button type="submit"></button>`
within a form element. When you click the button a traditional post back is performed, and the browser tries to post the form data to the server. Of course, this is not your intention. You only want to navigate within the space of your SPA App, right ?

To resolve this set the type attribute to "button", like this:

```
<button type="button"></button>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: You are right, I neglected. Thank you for your interest and solution.